# When using an ExecutorService, is it possible for a Thread to become uninterruptible when in the WAITING state

Tags: multithreading, java-8, jetty, executorservice, futuretask

I'm running into an issue where it seems as if a Thread has become uninterruptible while in a WAITING state.  The task thread itself (as you'll see in the stack of the thread below) is waiting for a call to FuturePromise.get() (a Jetty class).

The task thread is being executed in the context of an ExecutorService.  Below is what the ExecutorService invocation looks like (simplified).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8, new CustomizableThreadFactory("Test-Thread-"));
es.submit(taskToRun);
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
es.shutdownNow();
String result = taskToRun.get();
```

What I'm seeing is the main thread gets stuck at `taskToRun.get()` waiting for the task to complete/be interrupted while the thread running the task sits in this state:

```
"Test-Thread-1" 
#135245 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f972c0c2000 nid=0x6838 waiting on condition [0x00007f96ca165000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000005d00d1118> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:118)
... + app code
```

What I'm expecting to happen is `Test-Thread-1` will be interrupted which will throw an InterruptedException and the `taskToRun.get()` call would  also throw a InterruptedException.

Unfortunately I've been unable to reproduce this problem with a unit test, but will update as I get more info.

Comment: Are you expecting that `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` will cause the thread interrupt? (even tho the javadoc says it might not)

Comment: There is no prove that the job is inside `get()` method when interruption happens. There could be anything in your job, you didn’t show, including catching an `InterruptedException` or polling/clearing the interruption state before entering `get()`…

Comment: I'm a colleague of Mike's. We are expecting the `awaitTermination` to timeout the executor service and interrupt its threads. The `shutdownNow` is basically just a cleanup step assuming the executorService has either already finished its work or was timed out.

Comment: > could be anything in your job, you didn’t show, including catching an InterruptedException or polling/clearing the interruption state before entering get()

Right, so we didn't see anything that would have caught an InterruptedException anywhere else in our job. I guess we were confused exactly how the `executorService` handles these timeouts and when an InterruptedException would be thrown if we're not accessing `Future.get` until well after the shutdown has occurred. In theory, does the InterruptedException get stored internally and then re-thrown when Future.get is ultimately called?

Comment: @Bradley, `awaitTermination()` doesn't actually do the interrupting, the `shutdownNow()` does and the implementation being used (ThreadPoolExecutor) does appear to be using `Thread.interrupt()` to interrupt threads.

Comment: @Holger That's something I've considered and am trying to reproduce in a test case.  Essentially, creating a situation where the task thread is not in a state where it would respond to an interrupt (meaning our app code is not handling an interrupt).  Bottom line is that when the thread does get into the JVM code, it should be checking for interrupted status.  Afaik, our app code is not clearing the interrupted status on the thread, so once it gets into CountdownLatch, there are a number of different checks for the thread having been interrupted that should throw an InterruptedException.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, the implementation being used (ThreadPoolExecutor) appears to be issuing Thread.interrupt() calls to interrupt the threads.

Comment: Well, `LockSupport.park` will definitely return immediately when the thread has been interrupted and the AQS code is the base of almost every concurrency tool that supports locking or waiting. It’s hard to believe that there is a possibility of ignored interruption. Trying to be open to all possibilities, what about that `CustomizableThreadFactory`, can it return a subclass of `Thread` that overrides `interrupt()`?

Comment: This issue seems to have been addressed by upgrading to Jetty 9.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Jetty 9.4.6, this no longer seems to be a problem.  I did come across some [Jetty code that clears the interrupted state of threads](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.java#L674-L678), but it's not clear whether or not that was the actual cause.